# Android OpenGL ES 1.0 and GPU

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu

sorry for this question..
I'm using for my android app OpenGL ES 1.0 on Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini (CPU:1 GHz Dual-core ARM Cortex-A9, GPU: ARM Mali-400MP (single-core)).
OpenGL ES 1.0 use GPU during rendering? I need to enable or is done automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that this question does not show any research from your side, it all depends on the initialization of EGL.

Normally you specify which features you need (number of bits in the buffers, AntiAliasing enabled or not, etc). Based on these features OpenGL will select the most appropriate driver for you. If you don't select any exotic features, your rendering will be accelerated.

Have you read [OpenGL android developer documents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)?

Comment: Thank.. this question is because in Android Studio the chart of GPU show nothing during debug.. Only CPU usage is monitored.. So I supposed that the app doesn't use GPU..